# Check transformation values before applying the transform

Tags: wpf

I'm using a render transform to pan an image. I need the panning to stop at a certain point, so I'm checking the bounds of the image. The problem is that the image can be panned slightly beyond the bounds, because I'm checking the bounding box before the transform has been applied. Is there a way of applying the transform to the bounding box, then checking if this is within the valid range?

Thanks for any help

```
private void RecalculatePositions(MouseEventArgs e)
{
        TranslateTransform tt1 = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)this.image1.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        TranslateTransform tt2 = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)this.image2.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        Vector vector = this._startPoint - e.GetPosition(this.grid);

        double offsetX = this._originPoint.X - vector.X;
        double offsetY = this._originPoint.Y - vector.Y;

        Rect image1Bounds = this.image1.TransformToAncestor(this.viewBox1).TransformBounds(new Rect(this.image1.RenderSize));

        if (vector.X < 0)
        {
            //Moving image right
            if (offsetX <= 0)
            {
                tt1.X = offsetX;
                tt2.X = offsetX;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Moving image left
            if (image1Bounds.Right >= 0)
            {
                tt1.X = offsetX;
                tt2.X = offsetX;
            }
        }

        if (vector.Y < 0)
        {
            //Moving image down
            if (offsetY <= 0)
            {
                tt1.Y = offsetY;
                tt2.Y = offsetY;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Moving image up
            if (image1Bounds.Bottom >= this.ActualHeight)
            {
                tt1.Y = offsetY;
                tt2.Y = offsetY;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It's only a translation, so just add the appropriate x and y values to your bounds calculation. As a note, instead of independently transforming two Image elements, you could simply put them in a Panel (e.g. a Grid with two columns) and translate that by a single transformation.

Comment: Which values should I add? Both the vector and offset values are very big, and don't work with the stop conditions